# Snowflake integration with Azure Dev Ops

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Do you have information on how to integrate Snowflake with Azure devops for ci/cd.I see not much of information on docs.snowflake.com, I am interested in step by step process or guide of implementing the Azure devops  with Snowflake.

Comment: Our community has an article step by step, you can find it [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Snowflake-CI-CD-using-Flyway-and-Azure-DevOps-Pipeline-Part-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do this. You can install and execute SnowSQL, dbt or schemachange on ADO agents. Please see this guide for an example with schemachange. https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/devops_dcm_schemachange_azure_devops/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0